# Adding Local Tasks gives Page Not Found 404 error to all tabs excluding default tab using local tasks?

Tags: 8

Under custom_changes.links.task.yml

```
custom_changes.menu_example.tasks:
  route_name: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs
  title: Default primary tab
  base_route: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs
custom_changes.menu_example.task_view:
  route_name: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs_view
  title: Second
  base_route: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs
  weight: 2
custom_changes.menu_example.task_edit:
  route_name: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs_edit
  title: Third
  base_route: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs
  weight: 3
custom_changes.menu_example.task_delete:
  route_name: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs_delete
  title: Fourth
  base_route: custom_changes.menu_example.tabs
  weight: 4
```

Under StaticContent.php ( src\Controller\StaticContent.php )

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_changes\Controller;

use \Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

Class StaticContent extends ControllerBase  {
  public function static_callback() {
    $build = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World!'),
    ];
    return $build;
  }
  public function tabs() {
    $build = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World!'),
    ];
    return $build;
  }
  public function tabs_dynamic_view($id) {
    $build = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World! VIEW'. $id),
    ];
    return $build;
  }
  public function tabs_dynamic_edit($id) {
    $build = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World! EDIT'. $id),
    ];
    return $build;
  }
  public function tabs_dynamic_delete($id) {
    $build = [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello World! DELETE'. $id),
    ];
    return $build;
  }
```

Under custom_changes.routing.yml

```
custom_changes.menu_example.tabs:
  path: '/tabs'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Tabs'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_changes\Controller\StaticContent::tabs'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Access Tab Content'
custom_changes.menu_example.tabs_view:
  path: '/tabs/{id}/view'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Tabs View'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_changes\Controller\StaticContent::tabs_dynamic_view'
    id: 2
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Access Tab Content'
custom_changes.menu_example.tabs_edit:
  path: '/tabs/{id}/edit'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Tabs Edit'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_changes\Controller\StaticContent::tabs_dynamic_edit'
    id: 2
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Access Tab Content'
custom_changes.menu_example.tabs_delete:
  path: '/tabs/{id}/delete'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Tabs Delete'
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_changes\Controller\StaticContent::tabs_dynamic_delete'
    id: 2
  requirements:
    _permission: 'Access Tab Content'
```

I get Page Not Found 404 for Tabs View, Edit and Delete Tabs whereas it 
shows the default tab '/tabs'.
What is not correct in the code above?
[image]

It works when I remove {id} slug from routes.Does this support only static contents?

Comment: Not sure about those entries for id under default, have you tried it without?

Comment: Also the parent route needs to be /tabs/{id}  not /tabs

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong yes I have tried it without {id} and it worked as mentioned in the last line, Also, I tried with parent root as /tabs as well but I think that should not be the case , it should work even if its /tab Thanks and let me know if you can point more into it.

Comment: `$this->t('Hello World! VIEW'. $id),` might not be valid. Should be `$this->t('Hello World! VIEW @id', ['@id' => $id]),`

Comment: @harshal you're also setting a default of two,`id: 2`. This means that if someone goes to `/tabs/view`, 2 automatically gets passed when the id is missing. What Alfred is suggesting if for you to remove the `id: 2` so there is no default.

Comment: I removed removing default value of id, but still it does not work @NoSssweat

Comment: Are you clearing cache every time you make a change?

Comment: yes @AlfredArmstrong